# Please explain if Condition in this program

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, operators

Please Explain how if statement is working here I am new in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){

    int b=6,c=5;
    if (b++==7 && ++c==5)
    {
        b*=c;
        cout<<"IF OUTPUT IS "<<++b<<endl;
    }
    else 
        cout<<"ELSE 1ST OUTPUT "<<b--<<endl;
    cout<<"ELSE 2ND  OUTPUT IS "<<b<<endl;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Which part of that `if` statement is causing you confusion? The post-increment and pre-increment operators? The actual evaluation? Was there output for this that was confusing to you? If so, *what* ? All of that belongs [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72907204/edit)

Comment: You will be fired if you write if condition like this.

Comment: @Worry Nice, He already mentioned `I am new in c++`. I suggest here if you want to comment, should be done like `Better of writing this code would be XXXXX, If you write code the way you have written, It might look super Amateur `

Comment: @MuhammadTahirQaiser , Take it easy , I'm joking. He can't be fired without a job.

Comment: [here](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) Enclosing all sub-statements in parentheses (even those unnecessary because of their precedence) improves code readability.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code since inside the if condition you are checking post increment , (b++ ==7) and the initial value of b is 6 so the compiler first evaluates the first condition of b++==7 considering b=6 only and then modifies its value to 7 hence evaluating the initial condition as false because 6==7 results in false while for ++c==5 as this is pre increment it first modifies the value of c to 6 and then checks the condition 6===5 which is also false. Due to this both condition results in false and the program control goes to the else part of the code. In the else print considering post decrement in the first print statement the value of b is printed as 7 only and later on decremented by 1 printing 6 in next statement.

Comment: I doubt that `++c == 5` is executed at all. The logical And (`&&`) is evaluated short-circuit. That means in `(b++==7) && (++c==5)`: As you have explained correctly, `(b++ == 7)` results to `false`. Here, the evaluation of `&&` ends. Hence, no side-effects of the RHS of `&&` should appear and `c` keeps its initial value. [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78b27c6e86d486e2)

Comment: Are `&&` and `||` defined as sequence points?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow My practical reminder always has been `if (pSomething && pSomething->whatEver())` which wouldn't work otherwise -- based on the fact that it never broke so far. However, googling for this, I found [Sequence point rules (until C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Sequence_point_rules_.28until_C.2B.2B11.29), and `&&` and `||` are mentioned explicitly (among others). Scrolling to the top, you will find Evaluation Order Rules 6) which covers that part in the modern standards.